# Perl - Using my array to search for keywords in a file

Tags: regex, perl

I want my program to pull lines from a file that feature any of the keywords in an array, but it displays only the last keyword in the keywords file. How would I fix it to ensure that it finds all keywords?

```
use strict;
use warnings;

sub main {
    my $keywordFile = 'keyword.txt';
    open( keyWords, $keywordFile ) or die "$keywordFile not found\n";

    our @keywordArray = <keyWords>;
    while ( my $line = <keyWords> ) {
        push( @keywordArray, ($line) );
    }
    close(keyWords);

    my $fileName   = 'syslog.txt';
    my $outputFile = 'outputfile.txt';

    open( SysLog, $fileName ) or die "$fileName not found\n";
    open( my $fh, '>', $outputFile ) or die "$outputFile not found\n";

    while ( my $line = <SysLog> ) {
        foreach my $keyW (@keywordArray) {
            if ( $line =~ /$keyW/ ) {
                print "\n-------$keyW--------\n";
                print "$line";
                print $fh "$line";
            }
        }
    }
    close(SysLog);
    close $fh;
}

main();

print "\n";
```

Comment: Your keywords probably have newlines attached to them that are causing them not to match (see [chomp](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html)).

Comment: Also, some other things to be aware of: you're mixing filehandle styles, you probably _don't_ want `@keywordArray` to be a package variable (`our` vs. `my`), and you can use [`qr//`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/qr.html) to precompile your regexes for better performance (or use a module like [Regexp::Assemble](https://metacpan.org/pod/Regexp::Assemble)).

Comment: `grep -f keyword.txt syslog.txt > output.txt` perhaps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the strings in your `@keywordArray` contain newlines from the file.

You should use `chomp` to fix that (and you should use `my` in preference to `our`) so instead of

```
our @keywordArray = <keyWords>;
while ( my $line = <keyWords> ) {
    push( @keywordArray, ($line) );
}
```

you should write

```
my @keywordArray;
while ( my $line = <keyWords> ) {
    chomp $line;
    push @keywordArray, $line;
}
```

or, better

```
chomp(my @keywordArray = <keyWords>);
```

Here are some more important things to watch out for

- People who are familiar with high-quality Perl will thank you for using `snake_case` for your basic lexical variables. `CamelCase` is generally reserved for global identifiers such as package names
- It is good that you have used the *three-parameter* form of `open`, but you should also use *lexical* file handles. You have used a mixture of lexical and global handles, which is the worst option of all
- There is no need to put the whole of your program inside a subroutine and then call it. This isn't C
- If you test the status of an `open` call and find that it has failed, you should put the contents of the built-in variable `$!` in the `die` string to say *why* the open failed. There could be several reasons other than the *File not found* that you have coded. Better still, you can enable [`autodie`](http://metacpan.org/module/autodie), which will check all of your file system operations for you and generate an appropriate `die` string
- It is very rare that variables declared with `our` are useful. You should always use `my` unless you have a good reason to need a package variable
- `@keywordArray = <keyWords>` reads the whole of the file into the array, leaving it at eof. The following loop will never execute because there is nothing more to read from the file handle

Comment: Thank you so much for such an in depth explanation, it is much appreciated. :)

Answer (score 4):

You need to [chomp](http://p3rl.org/chomp) the lines to remove newlines.

Moreover, reading from a file handle in list context

```
our @keywordArray = <keyWords>;
```

reads the whole file, so nothing could be read in the following

```
while ( my $line = <keyWords> ) {
```

It's much faster to create one regex from all the keywords than to match each one separately:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

sub main {       
    my $keywordFile = 'keyword.txt';
    open $KW, $keywordFile or die "$keywordFile not found\n";
    chomp( my @keywords = <$KW> );
    my $keyword_regex = join '|', map quotemeta, @keywords;
    $keyword_regex = qr/($keyword_regex)/;

    my $fileName = 'syslog.txt';
    my $outputFile = 'outputfile.txt';

    open my $SL, $fileName or die "$fileName not found\n";
    open my $OUT, '>', $outputFile or die "$outputFile not found\n";

    while (my $line = <$SL>) {   
        if ($line =~ /$keyword_regex/) {
            print "\n-------$1--------\n";
            print "$line";
            print $OUT "$line";
        }
    }
    close $OUT;
}

main();
print "\n";
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are referring to the the fact that the output file contains only the last line which matched the keyword is because you are opening your output file for writing, which means that you are overwriting everything that you have previously written in it. You should open it for appending:

```
open(my $fh, '>>', $outputFile) or die "$outputFile not found\n";
```